# Using a collection and class V Dictionary in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a dashboard for someone so they can compare this years data on previous years. To start with, i have added a macro that allows them to search for both the new and old data. Then the macro opens these files. an example photo of the data has been provided in image 1.

The data is the number of visits to each venue each month, comparing current year to previous year.

Now, I want to rearrange the data so I can effectively use PivotTables to display what I would like. However I am not sure on the best way to do this. I have some VBA experience but not with dictionaries and collections/classes.

My idea was to use a class for each venue and then have a variable within that class for each month. Then store each months data into the variable. E.g. Venue1.Jun = 700. However, I would need to do this twice for old and new data.

I also though about transposing the row vertically to get all the visits into the correct months. But i would like it to be a bit more robust so use the venue as a key so it knows which one to input.

Again I have tried the transpose and got halfway, but the code is very inefficient with lots of declared variables etc.

What is the best way to go proceed with this? I have inputted my code below which aims to transpose the data spoken about before

#### Original Data

[image: Image1 OriginalData]

#### Required Output

[image: Image2, RequiredOutput]

```
Sub OldDataBrowser()
Dim OldDataDocPath As String
OldDataDocPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "File Document Path Browser")

If OldDataDocPath = "False" Then
    OldDataDocPath = ""
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B3").Value = OldDataDocPath

End Sub
Sub NewDataBrowser()
Dim DocPath As String
NewDataDocPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "File Document Path Browser")

If NewDataDocPath = "False" Then
    NewDataDocPath = ""
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B6").Value = NewDataDocPath

End Sub

Sub ExtractData()

Dim NewDataLocation As String: NewDataLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B6").Value
Dim OldDataLocation As String: OldDataLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B3").Value

Dim OldDataWb As Workbook: Set OldDataWb = Workbooks.Open(OldDataLocation)
Dim OldDataWs As Worksheet: Set OldDataWs = OldDataWb.Sheets("T1+T2")

Dim NewDataWb As Workbook: Set NewDataWb = Workbooks.Open(NewDataLocation)
Dim NewDataWs As Worksheet: Set NewDataWs = NewDataWb.Sheets("T1+T2")

Dim OutputtedWs As Worksheet: Set OutputtedWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")

Dim OldDataYear As String: OldDataYear = OutputtedWs.Cells(3, "C").Value
Dim NewDataYear As String: NewDataYear = OutputtedWs.Cells(6, "C").Value

Dim OldDataLastColNum As Long: OldDataLastColNum = NewDataWs.Cells(3, NewDataWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim OldDataLastColLet As String: OldDataLastColLet = Split(Cells(1, OldDataLastColNum).Address, "$")(1)

Dim OutputtedWsHeader As Variant: OutputtedWsHeader = Array("Venue", "Month", "Activity for " & OldDataYear & "", "Activity for " & NewDataYear & "", "Monthly % Change")
Dim Months As Variant: Months = Array("January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

Dim StartofData As String: StartofData = "Total visits by children and young people from UK"
Dim EndofData As String: EndofData = "Total UK visits"

Dim OldDataRangeStart As Variant: Set OldDataRangeStart = OldDataWs.range("A:A").Find(what:=StartofData, Lookat:=xlWhole)
Dim OldDataRangeEnd As Variant: Set OldDataRangeEnd = OldDataWs.range("A:A").Find(what:=EndofData, Lookat:=xlWhole)

Dim OldDatarange As range: Set OldDatarange = OldDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":" & OldDataLastColLet & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)
Dim newdatarange As range: Set newdatarange = NewDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":" & OldDataLastColLet & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)

Dim VenueArray As Variant
VenueArray = OldDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":A" & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)

OutputtedWs.range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = OutputtedWsHeader


Dim NumberofVenues, Numberofmonths As Long
NumberofVenues = UBound(VenueArray) - LBound(VenueArray)
Debug.Print (NumberofVenues)
Numberofmonths = UBound(Months) - LBound(Months)
Debug.Print (Numberofmonths)
'Debug.Print VenueArray(4)

OldDataWb.Close
NewDataWb.Close


'Loop through venues in array
For j = 1 To NumberofVenues
    Dim MonthLrow As Long: MonthLrow = OutputtedWs.range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Loop through rows to add the venue in column A and the month in column B
        For i = MonthLrow To (NumberofVenues + MonthLrow)
            OutputtedWs.Cells(i, 1).Value = VenueArray(j, 1).Value
            OutputtedWs.Cells(i, 2).Value = Months(i, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next i

    j = j + 1
Next j

'Loop throughh and add each row to array, than transpose the data.


End Sub
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
Sub OldDataBrowser()
Dim OldDataDocPath As String
OldDataDocPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "File Document Path Browser")

If OldDataDocPath = "False" Then
    OldDataDocPath = ""
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B3").Value = OldDataDocPath

End Sub
Sub NewDataBrowser()
Dim DocPath As String
NewDataDocPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "File Document Path Browser")

If NewDataDocPath = "False" Then
    NewDataDocPath = ""
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B6").Value = NewDataDocPath

End Sub

Sub ExtractData()

Dim NewDataLocation As String: NewDataLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B6").Value
Dim OldDataLocation As String: OldDataLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileImport").range("B3").Value

Dim OldDataWb As Workbook: Set OldDataWb = Workbooks.Open(OldDataLocation)
Dim OldDataWs As Worksheet: Set OldDataWs = OldDataWb.Sheets("T1+T2")

Dim NewDataWb As Workbook: Set NewDataWb = Workbooks.Open(NewDataLocation)
Dim NewDataWs As Worksheet: Set NewDataWs = NewDataWb.Sheets("T1+T2")

Dim OutputtedWs As Worksheet: Set OutputtedWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")

Dim OldDataYear As String: OldDataYear = OutputtedWs.Cells(3, "C").Value
Dim NewDataYear As String: NewDataYear = OutputtedWs.Cells(6, "C").Value

Dim OldDataLastColNum As Long: OldDataLastColNum = NewDataWs.Cells(3, NewDataWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim OldDataLastColLet As String: OldDataLastColLet = Split(Cells(1, OldDataLastColNum).Address, "$")(1)

Dim OutputtedWsHeader As Variant: OutputtedWsHeader = Array("Venue", "Month", "Activity for " & OldDataYear & "", "Activity for " & NewDataYear & "", "Monthly % Change")
Dim Months As Variant: Months = NewDataWs.range("B3:" & OldDataLastColLet & "3")

Dim StartofData As String: StartofData = "Total visits by children and young people from UK"
Dim EndofData As String: EndofData = "Total UK visits"

Dim OldDataRangeStart As Variant: Set OldDataRangeStart = OldDataWs.range("A:A").Find(what:=StartofData, Lookat:=xlWhole)
Dim OldDataRangeEnd As Variant: Set OldDataRangeEnd = OldDataWs.range("A:A").Find(what:=EndofData, Lookat:=xlWhole)

Dim OldDatarange As range: Set OldDatarange = OldDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":" & OldDataLastColLet & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)
Dim newdatarange As range: Set newdatarange = NewDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":" & OldDataLastColLet & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)

Dim NewDataVenueArray As Variant
NewDataVenueArray = NewDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":" & OldDataLastColLet & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)


Dim OldDataVenueArray As Variant
OldDataVenueArray = OldDataWs.range("A" & OldDataRangeStart.Row & ":" & OldDataLastColLet & OldDataRangeEnd.Row)

OutputtedWs.range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = OutputtedWsHeader


Dim NumberofVenues As Long
Dim Numberofmonths As Long
NumberofVenues = UBound(NewDataVenueArray) - LBound(NewDataVenueArray)
Numberofmonths = UBound(Months) - LBound(Months)

OldDataWb.Close
NewDataWb.Close

'Loop through venues in array
For j = 1 To NumberofVenues
    Dim MonthLrow As Long: MonthLrow = OutputtedWs.range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Loop through rows to add the venue in column A and the month in column B
        a = 1
        'Loop through and add each row to array, than transpose the data.
        For i = MonthLrow To (NumberofVenues + MonthLrow)
            OutputtedWs.Cells(i, 1).Value = NewDataVenueArray(j, 1).Value
            OutputtedWs.Cells(i, 2).Value = Months(1, a).Value
            OutputtedWs.Cells(i, 3).Value = OldDataVenueArray(j, a).Value
            OutputtedWs.Cells(i, 4).Value = NewDataVenueArray(j, a).Value
            a = a + 1
            i = i + 1
        Next i

    j = j + 1
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Couple of things: in `ExtractData` you should probably check if file locations have be provided for old and new data. Second: this line: `Dim NumberofVenues, Numberofmonths As Long`, it only declares `Numberofmonths` as long. `NumberofVenues` is declared as a variant. To declare them both as long in VBA, you have to declare them individually: `Dim NumberofVenues As Long, Numberofmonths As Long`

Comment: How are you populating **Activity For** columns?

Comment: I was going to get the data and put into an array and transpose it. But i was wondering if a collection/dictionary was better? And how would i use it

Comment: @Zac, I have updated the code above to include how i was originally going to input the values for activity for. I get an error of "Object required" on first row of the newly added code

Comment: I suspect when you setting `OldDataRangeStart`, `Find` didn't return any results and that's why you are getting that error. As far as **Array** or **Collection** is concerned, it depends on your range. If your range will only have a few thousand rows, you wont see much difference in speed. So the question of **"better"** I suspect is entirely subjective and in this case maybe equates to **"ease of use"**. I would suggest in that case array is **"better"** because it can be directly linked to a range

Comment: Is this line correct OldDataYear = OutputtedWs.Cells(3, "C").Value ? Should it not be OldDataWs. Are the number and order of venues in the Old and New workbooks identical ?